# Connect 4 in Java

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm trying to make a simple connect 4 game in Java. The idea is to make a 2-player game so there's no AI involved. I've made the board. However, i'm having trouble with getting the game to stop when someone wins. 
Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Connect4  extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
private JButton btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7;
private JButton Reset;
private JTextField[][] text;
private char myLabel;
private Moving mover;
private boolean win;
public boolean getWin(){
    return win;
}
public Connect4() {

    this.setLayout(null);
    this.setBounds(400,300, 600, 600);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.magenta);

    text = new JTextField [7][6]; 
    for (int a = 0 ; a < 7; a++) 
    {

        for (int b = 0; b < 6; b++) 
        {

            text[a][b] = new JTextField();
            add(text[a][b]);
            text[a][b].setBounds(50 + (a*70), (b+3) * 50 , 50, 50);
            text[a][b].addActionListener(this);

            Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 20);
            text[a][b].setFont(font);
            //text[a][b].setHorizontalAlignmen(JFormattedTextField.CENTER);

            text[a][b].setForeground(Color.red); 



        }


    }       

        mover = new Moving(text);

        btn1 = new JButton();
        add(btn1);
        btn1.setBounds(50, 50, 50, 50);
        btn1.addActionListener(this);


        btn2 = new JButton();
        add(btn2);
        btn2.setBounds(120, 50, 50, 50);
        btn2.addActionListener(this);


        btn3 = new JButton();
        add(btn3);
        btn3.setBounds(190, 50, 50, 50);
        btn3.addActionListener(this);

        btn4 = new JButton();
        add(btn4);
        btn4.setBounds(260, 50, 50, 50);
        btn4.addActionListener(this);

        btn5 = new JButton();
        add(btn5);
        btn5.setBounds(330, 50, 50, 50);
        btn5.addActionListener(this);

        btn6 = new JButton();
        add(btn6);
        btn6.setBounds(400, 50, 50, 50);
        btn6.addActionListener(this);

        btn7 = new JButton();
        add(btn7);
        btn7.setBounds(470, 50, 50, 50);
        btn7.addActionListener(this);


        Reset = new JButton("Reset");
        add(Reset);
        Reset.setBounds(200, 470, 150, 50);
        Reset.addActionListener(this);


}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Connect4();
}
int space1 = 5;
int space2 = 5;
int space3 = 5;
int space4 = 5;
int space5 = 5;
int space6 = 5;
int space7 = 5;

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    if (myLabel == 'X') { 
                    myLabel = 'O'; 
                } 
                else { 
                    myLabel = 'X'; 
                } 



        if (e.getSource() == btn1)
        {
            mover.start();
            text[0][space1].setText("" + myLabel);

            space1--;



    }
        if (space1 == -1)
        {
            btn1.setEnabled(false);


        }
    {
     if (e.getSource() == btn2)     
    {
            text[1][space2].setText("" + myLabel);

            space2--;

        } 
        if (space2 == -1)
        {
            btn2.setEnabled(false);
        }

     if (e.getSource() == btn3)     
    {
            text[2][space3].setText("" + myLabel);

            space3--;

        } 
        if (space3 == -1)
        {
            btn3.setEnabled(false);
        }

     if (e.getSource() == btn4)     
    {
            text[3][space4].setText("" + myLabel);

            space4--;

        } 
        if (space4 == -1)
        {
            btn4.setEnabled(false);
        }

    if (e.getSource() == btn5)      
    {
            text[4][space5].setText("" + myLabel);

            space5--;

        } 
    if (space5 == -1)
    {
        btn5.setEnabled(false);
    }

    if (e.getSource() == btn6)      
    {
            text[5][space6].setText("" + myLabel);

            space6--;

        } 
    if (space6 == -1)
    {
        btn6.setEnabled(false);
    }

    if (e.getSource() == btn7)      
    {
            text[6][space7].setText("" + myLabel);

            space7--;



        } 
    if (space7 == -1)
            {
                btn7.setEnabled(false);
            }

}
       if (e.getSource() == Reset)  
       {
           this.dispose();
           new Connect4();
       }

}

public class Moving extends Thread {
    JTextField text[][];
    public Moving(JTextField text[][])
    {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public void run () {
        for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
            text[0][y].setText("" + myLabel);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }   
            text[0][y].setText("");

        }


        for (int y=0; y < 4; y++) {
            text[0][y].setText("" + myLabel);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }   
            text[0][y].setText("");

}
    }
}
public void win(){
    //85 different wins
    //=========================================================================================
    if(text[3][1]==1&&text[4][2]==1&&text[5][3]==1&&text[6][4]==1||text[3][1]==2&&text[4][2]==2&&text[5][3]==2&&text[6][4]==2){

        win=true;
    }
    if(text[2][1]==1&&text[3][2]==1&&text[4][3]==1&&text[5][4]==1||text[3][2]==1&&text[4][3]==1&&text[5][4]==1&&text[6][5]==1
        ||text[2][1]==2&&text[3][2]==2&&text[4][3]==2&&text[5][4]==2||text[3][2]==2&&text[4][3]==2&&text[5][4]==2&&text[6][5]==2){

        win=true;
    }  
    if(text[1][1]==1&&text[2][2]==1&&text[3][3]==1&&text[4][4]==1
        ||text[2][2]==1&&text[3][3]==1&&text[4][4]==1&&text[5][5]==1
        ||text[3][3]==1&&text[4][4]==1&&text[5][5]==1&&text[6][6]==1

            ||text[1][1]==2&&text[2][2]==2&&text[3][3]==2&&text[4][4]==2
                    ||text[2][2]==2&&text[3][3]==2&&text[4][4]==2&&text[5][5]==2
                    ||text[3][3]==2&&text[4][4]==2&&text[5][5]==2&&text[6][6]==2){

        win=true;
    }
    if(text[1][2]==1&&text[2][3]==1&&text[3][4]==1&&text[4][5]==1
            ||text[2][3]==1&&text[3][4]==1&&text[4][5]==1&&text[5][6]==1
            ||text[3][4]==1&&text[4][5]==1&&text[5][6]==1&&text[6][7]==1

                ||text[1][2]==2&&text[2][3]==2&&text[3][4]==2&&text[4][5]==2
                        ||text[2][3]==2&&text[3][4]==2&&text[4][5]==2&&text[5][6]==2
                        ||text[3][4]==2&&text[4][5]==2&&text[5][6]==2&&text[6][7]==2){

        win=true;
    }
    if(text[1][3]==1&&text[2][4]==1&&text[3][5]==1&&text[4][6]==1
            ||text[2][4]==1&&text[3][5]==1&&text[4][6]==1&&text[5][7]==1

            ||text[1][3]==2&&text[2][4]==2&&text[3][5]==2&&text[4][6]==2
            ||text[2][4]==2&&text[3][5]==2&&text[4][6]==2&&text[5][7]==2){

        win=true;
    }
    if(text[1][4]==1&&text[2][5]==1&&text[3][6]==1&&text[4][7]==1||text[1][4]==2&&text[2][5]==2&&text[3][6]==2&&text[4][7]==2){

        win=true;
    }
    //=======================================================================================
    if(text[4][1]==1&&text[3][2]==1&&text[2][3]==1&&text[1][4]==1||text[4][1]==2&&text[3][2]==2&&text[2][3]==2&&text[1][4]==2){

    }
    if(text[5][1]==1&&text[4][2]==1&&text[3][3]==1&&text[2][4]==1||text[4][2]==1&&text[3][3]==1&&text[2][4]==1&&text[1][5]==1
        ||text[5][1]==2&&text[4][2]==2&&text[3][3]==2&&text[2][4]==2||text[4][2]==2&&text[3][3]==2&&text[2][4]==2&&text[1][5]==2){

        win=true;
    }  
    if(text[6][1]==1&&text[5][2]==1&&text[4][3]==1&&text[3][4]==1
        ||text[5][2]==1&&text[4][3]==1&&text[3][4]==1&&text[2][5]==1
        ||text[4][3]==1&&text[3][4]==1&&text[2][5]==1&&text[1][6]==1

        ||text[6][1]==2&&text[5][2]==2&&text[4][3]==2&&text[3][4]==2
        ||text[5][2]==2&&text[4][3]==2&&text[3][4]==2&&text[2][5]==2
        ||text[4][3]==2&&text[3][4]==2&&text[2][5]==2&&text[1][6]==2){

        win=true;
    }
    if(text[6][2]==1&&text[5][3]==1&&text[4][4]==1&&text[3][5]==1
        || text[5][3]==1 && text[4][4]==1 && text[3][5]==1 && text[2][6]==1
        ||text[4][4]==1 && text[3][5]==1 && text[2][6]==1 && text[1][7]==1

        ||text[6][2]==2&&text[5][3]==2&&text[4][4]==2&&text[3][5]==2
        ||text[5][3]==2&&text[4][4]==2&&text[3][5]==2&&text[2][6]==2
        ||text[4][4]==2&&text[3][5]==2&&text[2][6]==2&&text[1][7]==2){

        win=true;
    }
    if(text[6][3]==1&&text[5][4]==1&&text[4][5]==1&&text[3][6]==1
            ||text[5][4]==1&&text[4][5]==1&&text[3][6]==1&&text[2][7]==1

            ||text[6][3]==2&&text[5][4]==2&&text[4][5]==2&&text[3][6]==2
            ||text[5][4]==2&&text[4][5]==2&&text[3][6]==2&&text[2][7]==2){

    }
    if(text[6][4]==1&&text[5][5]==1&&text[4][6]==1&&text[3][7]==1||text[6][4]==2&&text[5][5]==2&&text[4][6]==2&&text[3][7]==2){

        win=true;
    }
    //=========================================================================================

    if(text[1][1]==1&&text[1][2]==1&&text[1][3]==1&&text[1][4]==1
        ||text[1][2]==1&&text[1][3]==1&&text[1][4]==1&&text[1][5]==1
        ||text[1][3]==1&&text[1][4]==1&&text[1][5]==1&&text[1][6]==1
        ||text[1][4]==1&&text[1][5]==1&&text[1][6]==1&&text[1][7]==1

        ||text[1][1]==2&&text[1][2]==2&&text[1][3]==2&&text[1][4]==2
        ||text[1][2]==2&&text[1][3]==2&&text[1][4]==2&&text[1][5]==2
        ||text[1][3]==2&&text[1][4]==2&&text[1][5]==2&&text[1][6]==2
        ||text[1][4]==2&&text[1][5]==2&&text[1][6]==2&&text[1][7]==2){


        win=true;
    }
    if(text[2][1]==1&&text[2][2]==1&&text[2][3]==1&&text[2][4]==1
            ||text[2][2]==1&&text[2][3]==1&&text[2][4]==1&&text[2][5]==1
            ||text[2][3]==1&&text[2][4]==1&&text[2][5]==1&&text[2][6]==1
            ||text[2][4]==1&&text[2][5]==1&&text[2][6]==1&&text[2][7]==1

            ||text[2][1]==2&&text[2][2]==2&&text[2][3]==2&&text[2][4]==2
            ||text[2][2]==2&&text[2][3]==2&&text[2][4]==2&&text[2][5]==2
            ||text[2][3]==2&&text[2][4]==2&&text[2][5]==2&&text[2][6]==2
            ||text[2][4]==2&&text[2][5]==2&&text[2][6]==2&&text[2][7]==2){


        win=true;

    }
    if(text[3][1]==1&&text[3][2]==1&&text[3][3]==1&&text[3][4]==1
            ||text[3][2]==1&&text[3][3]==1&&text[3][4]==1&&text[3][5]==1
            ||text[3][3]==1&&text[3][4]==1&&text[3][5]==1&&text[3][6]==1
            ||text[3][4]==1&&text[3][5]==1&&text[3][6]==1&&text[3][7]==1

            ||text[3][1]==2&&text[3][2]==2&&text[3][3]==2&&text[3][4]==2
            ||text[3][2]==2&&text[3][3]==2&&text[3][4]==2&&text[3][5]==2
            ||text[3][3]==2&&text[3][4]==2&&text[3][5]==2&&text[3][6]==2
            ||text[3][4]==2&&text[3][5]==2&&text[3][6]==2&&text[3][7]==2){


        win=true;
    }
    if(text[4][1]==1&&text[4][2]==1&&text[4][3]==1&&text[4][4]==1
            ||text[4][2]==1&&text[4][3]==1&&text[4][4]==1&&text[4][5]==1
            ||text[4][3]==1&&text[4][4]==1&&text[4][5]==1&&text[4][6]==1
            ||text[4][4]==1&&text[4][5]==1&&text[4][6]==1&&text[4][7]==1

            ||text[4][1]==2&&text[4][2]==2&&text[4][3]==2&&text[4][4]==2
            ||text[4][2]==2&&text[4][3]==2&&text[4][4]==2&&text[4][5]==2
            ||text[4][3]==2&&text[4][4]==2&&text[4][5]==2&&text[4][6]==2
            ||text[3][4]==2&&text[4][5]==2&&text[4][6]==2&&text[4][7]==2){


        win=true;
    }
    if(text[5][1]==1&&text[5][2]==1&&text[5][3]==1&&text[5][4]==1
            ||text[5][2]==1&&text[5][3]==1&&text[5][4]==1&&text[5][5]==1
            ||text[5][3]==1&&text[5][4]==1&&text[5][5]==1&&text[5][6]==1
            ||text[5][4]==1&&text[5][5]==1&&text[5][6]==1&&text[5][7]==1

            ||text[5][1]==2&&text[5][2]==2&&text[5][3]==2&&text[5][4]==2
            ||text[5][2]==2&&text[5][3]==2&&text[5][4]==2&&text[5][5]==2
            ||text[5][3]==2&&text[5][4]==2&&text[5][5]==2&&text[5][6]==2
            ||text[5][4]==2&&text[5][5]==2&&text[5][6]==2&&text[5][7]==2){


        win=true;
    }
    if(text[6][1]==1&&text[6][2]==1&&text[6][3]==1&&text[6][4]==1
            ||text[6][2]==1&&text[6][3]==1&&text[6][4]==1&&text[6][5]==1
            ||text[6][3]==1&&text[6][4]==1&&text[6][5]==1&&text[6][6]==1
            ||text[6][4]==1&&text[6][5]==1&&text[6][6]==1&&text[6][7]==1

            ||text[6][1]==2&&text[6][2]==2&&text[6][3]==2&&text[6][4]==2
            ||text[6][2]==2&&text[6][3]==2&&text[6][4]==2&&text[6][5]==2
            ||text[6][3]==2&&text[6][4]==2&&text[6][5]==2&&text[6][6]==2
            ||text[6][4]==2&&text[6][5]==2&&text[6][6]==2&&text[6][7]==2){


        win=true;
    }

    //===================================================================================================
    if(text[1][1]==1&&text[2][1]==1&&text[3][1]==1&&text[4][1]==1
            ||text[2][1]==1&&text[3][1]==1&&text[4][1]==1&&text[5][1]==1
            ||text[3][1]==1&&text[4][1]==1&&text[5][1]==1&&text[6][1]==1

            ||text[1][1]==2&&text[2][1]==2&&text[3][1]==2&&text[4][1]==2
            ||text[2][1]==2&&text[3][1]==2&&text[4][1]==2&&text[5][1]==2
            ||text[3][1]==2&&text[4][1]==2&&text[5][1]==2&&text[6][1]==2){


        win=true;

    }
    if(text[1][2]==1&&text[2][2]==1&&text[3][2]==1&&text[4][2]==1
            ||text[2][2]==1&&text[3][2]==1&&text[4][2]==1&&text[5][2]==1
            ||text[3][2]==1&&text[4][2]==1&&text[5][2]==1&&text[6][2]==1

            ||text[1][2]==2&&text[2][2]==2&&text[3][2]==2&&text[4][2]==2
            ||text[2][2]==2&&text[3][2]==2&&text[4][2]==2&&text[5][2]==2
            ||text[3][2]==2&&text[4][2]==2&&text[5][2]==2&&text[6][2]==2){

        win=true;
    }
    if(text[1][3]==1&&text[2][3]==1&&text[3][3]==1&&text[4][3]==1
            ||text[2][3]==1&&text[3][3]==1&&text[4][3]==1&&text[5][3]==1
            ||text[3][3]==1&&text[4][3]==1&&text[5][3]==1&&text[6][3]==1

            ||text[1][3]==2&&text[2][3]==2&&text[3][3]==2&&text[4][3]==2
            ||text[2][3]==2&&text[3][3]==2&&text[4][3]==2&&text[5][3]==2
            ||text[3][3]==2&&text[4][3]==2&&text[5][3]==2&&text[6][3]==2){

        win=true;
    }
    if(text[1][4]==1&&text[2][4]==1&&text[3][4]==1&&text[4][4]==1
            ||text[2][4]==1&&text[3][4]==1&&text[4][4]==1&&text[5][4]==1
            ||text[3][4]==1&&text[4][4]==1&&text[5][4]==1&&text[6][4]==1

            ||text[1][4]==2&&text[2][4]==2&&text[3][4]==2&&text[4][4]==2
            ||text[2][4]==2&&text[3][4]==2&&text[4][4]==2&&text[5][4]==2
            ||text[3][4]==2&&text[4][4]==2&&text[5][4]==2&&text[6][4]==2){

        win=true;
    }
    if(text[1][5]==1&&text[2][5]==1&&text[3][5]==1&&text[4][5]==1
            ||text[2][5]==1&&text[3][5]==1&&text[4][5]==1&&text[5][5]==1
            ||text[3][5]==1&&text[4][5]==1&&text[5][5]==1&&text[6][5]==1

            ||text[1][5]==2&&text[2][5]==2&&text[3][5]==2&&text[4][5]==2
            ||text[2][5]==2&&text[3][5]==2&&text[4][5]==2&&text[5][5]==2
            ||text[3][5]==2&&text[4][5]==2&&text[5][5]==2&&text[6][5]==2){

        win=true;
    }
    if(text[1][6]==1&&text[2][6]==1&&text[3][6]==1&&text[4][6]==1
            ||text[2][6]==1&&text[3][6]==1&&text[4][6]==1&&text[5][6]==1
            ||text[3][6]==1&&text[4][6]==1&&text[5][6]==1&&text[6][6]==1

            ||text[1][6]==2&&text[2][6]==2&&text[3][6]==2&&text[4][6]==2
            ||text[2][6]==2&&text[3][6]==2&&text[4][6]==2&&text[5][6]==2
            ||text[3][6]==2&&text[4][6]==2&&text[5][6]==2&&text[6][6]==2){

        win=true;
    }
    if(text[1][7]==1&&text[2][7]==1&&text[3][7]==1&&text[4][7]==1
            ||text[2][7]==1&&text[3][7]==1&&text[4][7]==1&&text[5][7]==1
            ||text[3][7]==1&&text[4][7]==1&&text[5][7]==1&&text[6][7]==1

            ||text[1][7]==2&&text[2][7]==2&&text[3][7]==2&&text[4][7]==2
            ||text[2][7]==2&&text[3][7]==2&&text[4][7]==2&&text[5][7]==2
            ||text[3][7]==2&&text[4][7]==2&&text[5][7]==2&&text[6][7]==2){

        win=true;
    }

}   
}
```

Comment: can you provide more details on what you're trying to do and what you've tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you are not calling the methods `getWin()` and `win()` anywhere in the above code

Comment: Yes, I am.. On line 17